# destructure nested array of unknown length

Tags: arrays, clojure

I am in the process of learning Clojure, and I have a question regarding the best way to code the following : I want to return the number which has the highest frequency in an array. This should be fairly easy given that there is a `frequency` method.

But I can't decide if my approach is idiomatic. Here is what I have :

```
(defn highest-rank [coll]
  (let [[element frequency] (first  (reverse (sort-by second (frequencies coll))))]
    element))
```

In particular, is it worth declaring a variable and use destructuring here ? Or should I just use `first` twice ?

Or should I destructure the whole array ? That way I could maybe make something more destriptive, like `sort-by frequency` ? Is it even possible ?

Which leads me to the technical part of this question : I know that I can destructure nested arrays like so `(let [[a,b] [c, d]] __)`, but how would that work for an array of unknown length ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to sort and reverse. Here's a simpler way to do it:

```
(defn highest-rank [coll]
  (first (apply max-key val (frequencies coll))))
```

Edit: As to your other question, you can destructure infinite collections, for example:

```
(let [[[a b] [c d] _ ] (map-indexed vector (range))] (println a b c d))
```

=> 0 0 1 1

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but I'm not sure yet that the destructuring part is what I asked (note that I'm not sure if I asked something feasible though).

Comment: `(map-indexed vector (range))` is an infinite sequence of pairs. You can destructure as many pairs as you want, and ignore the (infinite) rest, or destructure the rest as well and use it as an infinite sequence. BTW, you say "arrays" but you're dealing with sequences. They are not the same thing in Clojure.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. I get the (lazy?) generation of the infinite sequence. So what you say is that I would have to loop/recurse over the rest of the sequence in my example ? I was aiming for something like "do something for every val1 of [ unknown length nested array of the form [val1 val2] ]". Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can destructure a collection of unknown length:

```
(let [[[a b] [c d] & _] the-collection] do-something)
```

You wonderer "is it worth...", why not just type both versions down and compare them? Destructuring forms will expand to `first`, `rest` etc... so it's all about code readability. In this case, `first` is better.